# Matlab MATPOWER Output in long format

Tags: matlab, long-integer, matpower

I've been trying to use MATPOWER to do a power flow analysis for a network i have but all the outputs are coming with only 2 decimal places. Is there a way to configure the output to have the long format?

Comment: Try writing format long in the Matlab prompt. It will change Matlab's display settings to display something like 14 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Trota,

You can modify the number of decimal places printed on screen or forwarded to the output text file.
If you browse the printpf.m file, simply change the required %9.xf to the required number of decimal places, where x is the number of digits after the decimal point. For bus data, these can be found at line 412 onwards.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the number of decimal places used in the pretty-printed output of MATPOWER, but all of the results are available in full precision in the results struct returned by runpf() or runopf(). You can display these results with whatever precision you choose using standard Matlab commands such as disp() or fprintf().